# Working in MY SQL but not in MS SQL Server or ORACLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On HackerRAnk this " https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-report/problem " was the Question .
I Wrote This code .

```
SELECT (CASE 
       WHEN (STUDENTS.MARKS>=70) THEN (STUDENTS.NAME)
       ELSE "NULL"
       END) , GRADES.GRADE , STUDENTS.MARKS FROM STUDENTS
INNER JOIN GRADES ON
                    STUDENTS.MARKS BETWEEN MIN_MARK AND MAX_MARK
ORDER BY GRADES.GRADE DESC, (CASE
         WHEN (STUDENTS.MARKS>=70) THEN  STUDENTS.NAME
         ELSE  STUDENTS.MARKS
         END) ;
```

I was using MS SQL but this was showing error :-
    **Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 2 
    Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Priya' to data type int.**

But the Same Code worked for My SQL. Please Help.
And can anyone suggest what's the best SQL to learn that's Widely used, and from where.?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: string constants should be enclosed in single quotes. Double quotes are used for identifiers. So you should use `'NULL'`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Name` is a string and `marks` is a number, this code should not work in ANY database:

```
(CASE WHEN STUDENTS.MARKS >= 70 THEN STUDENTS.NAME
      ELSE STUDENTS.MARKS
 END) ;
```

However, MySQL does a form of implicit conversion where it sometimes converts strings to numbers without generating an error.  So it might not return an error in this case, instead converting a name like `'Pat'` to `0`.  (I'm not 100% sure in this case; I avoid mixing types like this.)

The reason is that a `CASE` expression returns a single type.  In SQL, when there is a choice between a number and a string, the number wins.  So, you'll get a type-conversion error.

It is unclear what you intend, but I might guess:

```
ORDER BY GRADES.GRADE DESC,
         (CASE WHEN STUDENTS.MARKS >= 70 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),       -- higher marks first
         (CASE WHEN STUDENTS.MARKS >= 70 THEN STUDENTS.NAME END),  -- higher marks by name
         STUDENTS.MARKS
```

Comment: Thanks , this taught me a lot about how thinks works in SQL .

Answer (score 2):

SQL is different for every RDBMS you are using, it is rare that code that works on one will work on another unless it very basic and uses no vendor specific functionality (and MySQL is full of non-generic behaviours imo...). You have to cater for the specific RDBMS you are using.

Here you have 2 problems. Firstly your `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`. If the `WHEN` evaluates to true, then `STUDENTS.NAME` will be returned, if not `STUDENTS.MARKS`.

`STUDENTS.NAME` is clearly an `(n)varchar`, however, `STUDENTS.MARKS` is likely an `int`, therefore the name of the student will be implicitly converted to an `int`, and that conversion will fail (surprise, `'Priya'` isn't a valid integer value). It seems you like want:

```
ORDER BY GRADES.GRADE,
         CASE STUDENTS.MARKS>=70 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         STUDENTS.NAME,
         STUDENTS.MARKS;
```

You also have a problem in the `CASE` in the `SELECT`. `"NULL"` means return the value of the column called `NULL` (`"` is the ANSI delimit identifier), not the value `NULL` (or `varchar` value `'NULL'`). Considering, however, that a `CASE` returns `NULL` if none of the expressions return true, you can actually just remove the `ELSE` clause entirely.

Comment: Tank you for your time and explanation , this too helped me a lot .

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is, the CASE expression should have same datatype for all cases.

Your code below is the problem. It is having Students.Name which is Priya and it is a character field. Students.Marks is integer field and you have issue.

```sql
     (CASE
             WHEN (STUDENTS.MARKS>=70) THEN  STUDENTS.NAME
             ELSE  STUDENTS.MARKS
             END) ;
```

What you have to do is, you have to have same datatype.

```sql
   (CASE
             WHEN (STUDENTS.MARKS>=70) THEN  STUDENTS.NAME
             ELSE  CAST(Students.MARKS AS VARCHAR(30))
             END) ;
```

Comment: Thanks , a lot ,For your explanation , I do Learned a lot from you , I'm fairly new at it and trying to learn by solving problem and wasted a lot of time on this Question cause I knew my Approach was right .